# Is there a way to access the attributes of my Entity from the Dao ? (Room)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

```
    @Query("UPDATE my_table SET name = :model.name")
    fun update(model : MyModel)
```

As you can see, i can't access the `name` attribute. How should i do ?

Comment: can i question why are you need that?

Comment: I want to update my entity on a numerous number of columns. So it's quite convenient to be able to do that...

Comment: Why don't you use @Update instead of @Query()?

Comment: I don't really know the syntax for @Update :/

Comment: Just replace @Query(…) with @Update annotation. This will find the entity MyModel with the same primary key and update it.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to update certain columns, you can use:

```
@Query("UPDATE my_table SET column_name = :name, (other columns) WHERE column_id = :id")
fun update(id : long, name : String, other columns);
```

**Note: id being the primary key.**

Comment: thank you ! So no choice to pass the names of all attributes in the function?

Comment: Because you need to update certain columns, then you have to pass the columns that you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@Query("UPDATE my_table SET name = :modelName")
fun update(modelName : String)
```

Therefore, you shall only pass the model name.

Room does also provide a direct method to update the object as a whole:

```
@Update
fun update(model : MyModel)
```

But consider the fact, that this method updates all attributes, not only the name.

Comment: thank you for your help. But I'm not looking to update all the columns.

Comment: well then, the first snippet is your way to go

Answer (score 1):

if you want update your model just use @Update annotations

```
@Update
fun update(model : MyModel)
```

this function automatically update your model

For update all columns use this

```
@Update
fun update(model : List<MyModel>)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. But I'm not looking to update all the columns ^^